# Is there a free open source version of Android SDK available for use?

Tags: open-source-definition, android, binaries, eula

When I download Android SDK from https://developers.android.com, I am prompted to agree with Google's EULA.

What should I use in order to avoid agreeing on these terms?

I'm under impression that Android SDK itself is a free software.

Comment: moved from https://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: See also: ttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/22420726/is-android-studio-an-open-source-project

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The source code itself is available here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/master/

There is Android Rebuilds project which provides binaries built from this source code without non-free EULA:
https://android-rebuilds.beuc.net/

Comment: The Android Rebuilds site is inaccessible, but according to https://forum.f-droid.org/t/android-rebuilds-beuc-net-seems-to-be-down/15021 it is supposed to redirect to https://gitlab.com/android-rebuilds